# Unable to execute loop in react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to run a react loop to display time, and am running into an issue, please assist. 
Below is my code

```
    populateDefaultTime() {
        alert("inside default time");
        for (let i = 1; i < 24; i++) {
            this.times.push(i);
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
         this.populateDefaultTime();
    }
```

Below is my error

```
populateDefaultTime() {
  35 |     alert("inside default time");
  36 |     for (let i = 1; i < 24; i++) {
> 37 |         this.times.push(i);
     | ^  38 |     }
  39 |    
  40 | }
```

Comment: You should use `setState` to update your states correctly

Answer (score 1):

`this.times` is not defined so you can't push to it. Should be:

```
this.state.times.push(i);
```

As @swapnesh has stated though you should not mutate state directly. It would be better to do something like

```
this.setState({ times: this.state.times.concat(i) });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Loop can't be used like that. You have to make use of state and the rest of React patterns and principles.
```

```js
const {
  useEffect,
  useState
} = React;
const lp = (n) => n <= 9 ? `0${n}` : n;
const Clock = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(new Date());
  const hours = lp(time.getHours());
  const minutes = lp(time.getMinutes());
  const seconds = lp(time.getSeconds());

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => setTime(new Date()), 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, []);

  return <div > {
    hours
  }: {
    minutes
  }: {
    seconds
  } < /div>
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Clock, {}, null), document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.profiling.min.js"></script>
```